# quick question about numerical methods for linear systems

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

let $Ax = b$ be a linear n by n system

and $x^*$ is a numerical solution of this system

I noticed that the relative error related to the solution of the system is necessarily small if $||b-Ax^*||_2$ is small is that true in general ?

I don't know how I can try to prove this any help or hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Should be; isn't relative error just $\| b- A x^* \|_2 / \|b\|_2$? So up to a rescaling?

Comment: Relative error is not relative residual as asked in the comment above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume there is a unique true solution $x = A^{-1} b$ (in particular, $A$ is invertible), and $b \ne 0$ (the relative error with respect to a true solution of $0$ would be meaningless).   The relative error is 
$$RE = \frac{\|x^* - x\|}{\|x\|}$$

Now $$\frac{\|A x^* - b\|}{\|x\|} = \frac{\|A(x^* - x)\|}{\|x\|} \le \frac{\|A\| \|x^* - x\|}{\|x\|} = \|A\| RE  $$
while in the other direct

Suppose $x^*$ is the approximate solution and $x$ the actual solution. ion
$$ RE = \frac{\| A^{-1} (A x^* - b) \|}{\|x\|} \le \|A^{-1}\| \frac{\|A x^* - b \|}{\|x\|} $$

Thus if neither $\|A\|$ nor $\|A^{-1}\|$ is too big or too small, smallness of
the relative error is associated with smallness of $\|A x^*-b\|/\|x\|$.

Comment: The second part seems to be the one that matters here.

Comment: Probably it is worth mentioning explicitly the related notion of conditioning number https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number.